# MySQL join query performance issue

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, indexing

I am running the be query

```
SELECT packages.id, packages.title, subcat.id, packages.weight
FROM packages ,provider, packagestosubcat, 
     packagestocity, subcat, usertosubcat, 
     usertocity, usertoprovider 
WHERE packages.endDate >'2011-03-11 06:00:00' AND 
      usertosubcat.userid = 1 AND 
      usertocity.userid = 1 AND 
      packages.providerid = provider.id AND 
      packages.id = packagestosubcat.packageid AND 
      packages.id = packagestocity.packageid AND 
      packagestosubcat.subcatid = subcat.id AND 
      usertosubcat.subcatid = packagestosubcat.subcatid AND 
      usertocity.cityid = packagestocity.cityid AND 
      (
          provider.providertype = 'reg' OR 
          (
              usertoprovider.userid = 1 AND 
              provider.providertype != 'reg' AND 
              usertoprovider.providerid = provider.ID
          )
      ) 
GROUP BY packages.title 
ORDER BY subcat.id, packages.weight DESC
```

When i run explain, everything seems to look ok except for the scan on the usertoprovider table, which doesn't seem to be using table's keys:

```
id select_type table            type    possible_keys         key       key_len ref                       rows Extra
1  SIMPLE      usertocity       ref     user,city             user      4       const                     4    Using temporary; Using filesort
1  SIMPLE      packagestocity   ref     city,packageid        city      4       usertocity.cityid         419  
1  SIMPLE      packages         eq_ref  PRIMARY,enddate       PRIMARY   4       packagestocity.packageid  1    Using where
1  SIMPLE      provider         eq_ref  PRIMARY,providertype  PRIMARY   4       packages.providerid       1    Using where
1  SIMPLE      packagestosubcat ref     subcatid,packageid    packageid 4       packages.id               1    Using where
1  SIMPLE      subcat           eq_ref  PRIMARY               PRIMARY   4       packagestosubcat.subcatid 1  
1  SIMPLE      usertosubcat     ref     userid,subcatid       subcatid  4       const                     12   Using where
1  SIMPLE      usertoprovider   ALL     userid,providerid     NULL      NULL    NULL                      3735 Using where
```

As you can see in the above query, the condition itself is:

```
provider.providertype = 'reg' OR 
(
    usertoprovider.userid = 1 AND 
    provider.providertype != 'reg' AND 
    usertoprovider.providerid = provider.ID
)
```

Both tables, provider and usertoprovider, are indexed. provider has indexes on providerid and providertype while usertoprovider has indexes on userid and providerid

The cardinality of the keys is:
provider.id=47, provider.type=1, usertoprovider.userid=1245, usertoprovider.providerid=6

So its quite obvious that the indexes are not used.

Further more, to test it out, i went ahead and:

- Duplicated the usertoprovider table
- Inserted all the provider values that have providertype='reg' into the cloned table
- Simplified the condition to (usertoprovider.userid = 1 AND usertoprovider.providerid = provider.ID)

The query execution time changed from **8.1317 sec.** to **0.0387 sec.**

Still, provider values that have providertype='reg' are valid for all the users and i would like to avoid inserting these values into the usertoprovider table for all the users since this data is redundant.

Can someone please explain why MySQL still runs a full scan and doesn't use the keys? What can be done to avoid it?

Comment: Could you give the CREATE TABLE statements and wrap your query over multiple lines?
You might want to check index hinting: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/index-hints.html

Comment: Sorry for the mess, I've sorted out the info.

Comment: Hmm... for these kinds of joins I really suggest you use the ANSI-JOIN syntax. Just makes things more readable, and you can easily separate actual predicates from JOIN conditions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `provider.providertype != 'reg'` is redundant (always true) unless provider.providertype is nullable and you want the query to fail on NULL.

And shouldn't `!=` be `<>` instead to be standard SQL, although MySQL may allow `!=`?

### On cost of table scans

It is not necessarily that a full table scan is more expensive than walking an index, because walking an index still requires multiple page accesses.  In many database engines, if your table is small enough to fit inside a few pages, and the number of rows are small enough, it will be cheaper to do a table scan.  Database engines make this type of decision based on the data and index statistics of the table.

### This case

However, in your case, it might also be because of the other leg in your OR clause: `provider.providertype = 'reg'`.  If providertype is "reg", then this query joins in ALL the rows of usertoprovider (most likely not what you want) since it is a multi-table cross join.

The database engine is correct in determining that you'll likely need all the table rows in usertoprovider anyway (unless none of the providertype's is "reg", but the engine also may know!).

The query hides this fact because you are grouping on the **(MASSIVE!)** result set later on and just returning the package ID, so you won't see how many usertoprovider rows have been returned.  But it will run very slowly.  Get rid of the GROUP BY clause to find out how many rows you are actually forcing the database engine to work on!!!

The reason you see a massive speed improvement if you fill out the usertoprovider table is because then every row participates in a join, and there is no full cross join happening in the case of "reg".  Before, if you have 1,000 rows in usertoprovider, every row with type="reg" expands the result set 1,000 times.  Now, that row joins with only one row in usertoprovider, and the result set is not expanded.

If you really want to pass anything with providertype='reg', but not in your many-to-many mapping table, then the easiest way may be to use a sub-query:

1. Remove usertoprovider from your FROM clause
2. Do the following:

`provider.providertype='reg' OR EXISTS (SELECT * FROM usertoprovider WHERE userid=1 AND providerid = provider.ID)`

Another method is to use an OUTER JOIN on the usertoprovider -- any row with "reg" which is not in the table will come back with *one* row of NULL instead of expanding the result set.

Comment: Newer MySQL-Versions allow both '<>' and '!='

Comment: OK.  :-)  Don't know that, but usually a good idea to stick to standard SQL lingo.

Comment: The entries in the provider table have two different providertype values and not a single value. When i duplicated the usertoprovider table and added all the entries that have providertype='reg' from the provider table into the usertoprovider table. Changed the query to (usertoprovider.userid = 1 AND usertoprovider.providerid = provider.ID) the query time went down from 8.1317 sec to 0.0387 sec. Still, since provider entries that have providertype='reg' are valid to all the users, i would like to avoid the redundant data and not insert them into the usertoprovider table for all the users.

Comment: You'll need to modify your query then.  As it currently stands, if it is "reg", it cross joins the *entire* usertoprovider table. Say, if you have 20 rows with "reg", and 100 rows in usertoprovider, your result set is expanded by 2,000 times. This unintended cross join is the reason why your query runs like a dog. See my edits for clarification.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, removing the usertoprivder from the FROM clause and refining the conditions solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I know that MySQL does funny things with grouping. In any other RDBMS, your query won't even be executed. What does that even mean,

```
SELECT packages.id 
[...]
GROUP BY packages.title 
ORDER BY subcat.id, packages.weight DESC
```

You want to group by `title`. Then in standard SQL syntax, this means you can only select `title` and aggregate functions of the other columns. MySQL magically tries to execute (and probably guess) what you may have meant to execute. So what would **you** expect to be selected as `packages.id` ? The First matching package ID for every `title`? Or the last? And what would the `ORDER BY` clause mean with respect to the grouping? How can you order by columns that are not part of the result set (because only `packages.title` really is)?

There are two solutions, as far as I can see:

1. You're on the right track with your query, then remove the `ORDER BY` clause, because I don't think it will affect your result, but it may severely slow down your query.
2. You have a SQL problem, not a performance problem

Comment: Lukas, that's my bad. I wanted to simplify the query in the post so I've removed all the values from select that didn't have any meaning. I mistakenly didn't notice that the query, as it is, will not execute. I am going to fix the post now.

Comment: It still doesn't make sense to me, but maybe that's not the reason for the performance problem... Why don't you group by `packages.id, packages.title, subcat.id, packages.weight` ?

Comment: There is a business limitation that forces me to insert multiple rows into the packages table. This results in some users getting the same package in their result because the same package will appear twice in the packages table with two different ids. Because of this limitation, i can't force the title field to be unique and the group by title enforces that users will only get a package once.